# Boost compiling with MSVC 11 (VS 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, boost-build

How to build *Boost* (I tried version [1.48.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_48_0.html)) with [Visual Studio C++ 11](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27538)? `bootstrap.bat` cannot find toolset `vc11`. I added toolset vc11 to `F:\Programming\boost_1_48_0\tools\build\v2\engine\build.bat` but got a message:

```
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
```

***EDIT:*** The *Ferruccio* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8220135/723845) works for VS 2012 Express and Boost 1.51.0 too.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) **unfortunately, not even "Visual Studio 2017" is fully `C++11` compliant** (I got here while building `Boost`, which's build section nowadays only mentions their need for `C++11` compliant compiler, and NOT with what `MSVC` version they tested `Boost`). Microsoft says "Support for C11 and C17 standards is available in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and later", but not tested their claim yet.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I managed to get it to build by following these steps:

1. Open a Visual Studio command prompt. From the start menu it's: All Programs|Microsoft Visual Studio 11|Native x64 Command Prompt.
2. Unzip boost_1_48_0.zip and set the working directory to boost_1_48_0
3. run bootstrap.bat
4. run bjam.exe

It does generate a lot of warnings about not being able to detect the toolkit version, but it proceeds anyway.

**Update:** I created GitHub repo called [cclibs](https://github.com/ferruccio/cclibs) which makes it simpler to build Boost and some other C++ libraries.

Comment: Thanks for this, alot easier than the boost doc's imply

Comment: Beware if you have `doskey.exe` executing via `(HKCU||HKLM)\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor: reg_sz AutoRun`.  Build caused `doskey` to crash and build to fail.  I have filed [a ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9488).

Answer (score 39):

This answer works beautifully for:

- `VS2012` (Visual Studio 2012 Update 2)

  - or `VS2015` (Visual Studio 2015 Update 2)
- Windows 7 x64

  - or Windows 10 x64
- Boost v1.53

  - or Boost v1.60

**In a nutshell**

1. Open a Visual Studio 2012 command prompt. From the start menu its: `All Programs..Microsoft Visual Studio 2012..Visual Studio Tools..x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`.
2. Unzip `boost_1_53_0.zip` to `C:\boost153`.
3. run `bootstrap.bat`
4. run `bjam.exe`
5. In any new C++ project, include the path to the Boost libraries, as per the screenshot below.

**(optional) Step-by-Step Instructions**

1. Install Visual Studio 2012.
2. Install Update 2.
3. Download [Boost from SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/).
4. Unzip into "C:\boost153"
5. Open a Visual Studio Command prompt with Administrator privileges. From the start menu, its `All Programs..Microsoft Visual Studio 2012..Visual Studio Tools..x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`.
6. Change to the boost directory with `cd c:\boost153`.
7. Run `bootstrap.bat`.
8. Run `bjam.exe`. This builds all of the libraries.
9. There may be some warnings, but you can ignore these.
10. When it has finished compiling after about 5 minutes, it states:

    ```
    The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
    The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
       C:/boost153
    The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
       C:\boost153\stage\lib
    ```
11. This is important, we will need to add these two paths to any new C++ project.
12. Create a new C++ project.
13. As noted a couple of steps ago, add `C:/boost153` to the `compiler include path` and `C:\boost153\stage\lib` to the `linker library path`.
14. Right click on the project, select `Properties`, select `Configuration Properties..VC++ Directories`. See the two portions of bolded text in the screenshot below):
    [image]
15. Let's run a simple program that shows off the power of boost, by adding support for `foreach` loops:

    ```
    // Source code below copied from:   
    // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/foreach.html
    #include "stdafx.h"

    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h> // Supports _getch()
    #include <boost/foreach.hpp>

    int main()
    {
        std::string hello( "Hello, world!" );

        BOOST_FOREACH( char ch, hello )
        {
            std::cout << ch;
        }

        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
    ```
16. Result:

    ```
    Hello, world!
    ```

#### More Answers

- See [Boost compiling with MSVC 11 (VS 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204758/boost-compiling-with-msvc-11-vs-2012).
- See [Official Boost docs on compiling with Visual Studio under Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).
- See [Building Boost v1.64](https://studiofreya.com/2017/04/23/building-boost-1-64-with-visual-studio-2017/).

#### Update 2016-05-05

Checked with `Win10 x64` + `VS2015.2` + `Boost v1.6.0`.

Comment: This build not all libraries

Comment: To build other desired libraries, add options to the `bjam` or `b2` command. Some common switches are building libraries for static/shared, x32/x64, etc.

Answer (score 8):

bootstrap.bat

bjam.exe --toolset=msvc-11

Comment: Or since boost 1.47.0 `b2 --toolset=msvc-11`. 
This answer seems far more correct than rerunning bootstrap from the dev shell and ignoring the upcomming warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Check that your installation is correct by confirming the output of the following command:

```
C:\>echo %VS110COMNTOOLS%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
```

Here's some simple instructions to follow to get rid of warnings when bootstrapping: http://landoftheninja.blogspot.com/2011/11/visual-c-11-and-boost.html

Don't miss his follow-up post that deals with the automatic linking.

Answer (score 0):

vs2012 ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

vcvarsall.bat need call a "reg.exe" which in "C:\windows\system32\".
if not in search path,will cause this error.

Add C:\windows\system32 to %PATH% will solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers, I find [BlueGo](http://vertexwahn.de/bluego.html) really helpful for building boost versions with MSVC 10/11/12. You can select different configurations and just select build, and it does the trick.